# Kotlin Coroutine Testing with Dispatchers.IO

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So maybe there has been a tutorial going over this, but none of the ones I have read have addressed this issue for me. I have the structure as below and am trying to unit test, but when I go to test I always fails stating the repo method `doSomthing()` was never called. My best guess is because i have launched a new coroutine in a different context. How do I test this then?

Repository

```
interface Repository {
    suspend fun doSomething(): String
}
```

View Model

```
class ViewModel(val repo: Repository) {
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    fun doSomething {
    //Do something here
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val data = repo.doSomething()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                liveData.value = data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View Model Test

```
class ViewModelTest {
    lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel
    lateinit var repo: Repository

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(TestCoroutineDispatcher())
        repo = mock<Repository>()
        viewModel = ViewModel(repo)
    }

    @Test
    fun doSomething() = runBlockingTest {
        viewModel.doSomething()
        viewModel.liveData.test().awaitValue().assertValue {
            // assert something
        }
        verify(repo).doSomthing()
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `viewModelScope` set up? If you expose it to the test, you could write `viewModelScope.coroutineContext[Job]!!.children.forEach { it.join() }`. However, this is still flaky because the test has no idea really how many child jobs you're going to launch and when they will be launched. You might get an empty `children` list. The way I handle a similar concern is by using an `assertTrueEventually` primitive that keeps retrying the assertion until it's satisfied or until a timeout elapses.

Comment: Also, I have a general comment on your code: it would be better design to launch the coroutine in the Main dispatcher and have `suspend fun doSomething()` that internally uses the IO dispatcher as needed. This shouldn't be the concern of the caller.

Comment: viewModelSCope is an extension function provided by Android which uses Dispatchers.Main... @MarkoTopolnik

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to Google:
[image]

`Dispatchers` should be injected into your `ViewModels` so you can properly test. You are setting the `TestCorotutineDispatcher` as the main Dispatcher via `Dispatchers.setMain` which takes control over the `MainDispatcher`, but you still have no control over the the execution of the coroutine launched via `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)`.

Passing the `Dispatcher` via the constructor would make sure that your test and production code use the same dispatcher.

Typically an `@Rule` is defined that:

1. Overrides the MainDispatcher via `Dispatchers.setMain` (like you are doing)
2. Uses the `TestCoroutineDispatcher's` own `runBlockingTest()` to actually run the test.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMb0Fs8rCRs) is a really nice talk about testing and coroutines that happened at last year's Android Dev Summit.

And [here](https://github.com/emmano/android-mva/blob/master/app/src/test/java/me/emmano/androidmva/rule/CoroutineTestRule.kt) is an example of such an `@Rule`. (Shameless plug. There are also examples of coroutine tests on that repo as well)

Comment: That's great! It is possible also to use default Dispatcher by overloading the viewModel constructor - in Kotlin `class MyViewModel( private val dispatcher : CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO)`  That way I need to set the dispatcher only when testing.

Comment: The Dispatchers.setMain does not seem to have an effect on Dispatchers.IO ? Or should it?

Answer (score 3):

I write this solution for who use Dagger.

Inject CoroutineDispatcher in ViewModel constructor like this:

```
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) : BaseViewModel() {
```

and Provide Dispatcher like this:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideDispatchers(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
```

and in test package, Provide Dispatcher like this:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideDispatchers(): CoroutineDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
```

and now all lines in viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) will be run

Answer (score 3):

```
@Test
fun ex() {
    mockkStatic(Dispatchers::class)
    val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
    every { Dispatchers.IO } returns dispatcher
    testedFunc()
    //dispatcher.scheduler.advanceUntilIdle()
    assert(true)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Comment: This appear to be a quicker solution compare to having to DI dispatchers, esp when you have supply both IO and Main